# Faint beeping sound from laptop

Tags: laptop, noise

I am using a Lenovo ThinkPad W530 and occasionally, when I start up the laptop I hear a faint beep noise coming from inside the laptop itself. What is the source of this noise? How can I stop it? I've read somewhere online that it could be an internal speaker used to notify the user of some kind of error.

Comment: is it a single beep?  describe exactaly when it occurs , what is the next thing you see visually in the process?  Does it occur any other time other than "start-Up"?  On the "ocasionally" is the difference that you were on standy not powered fully off? Provide as much info as you can.

Comment: It is a constant beeping noise that I hear. It's hard to detect if the speakers are on or when there is background noise. 
When I put the computer to sleep or shut it down, the noise is gone.

Comment: Constant beeping is not a good sign. Does the computer work normally? What operating system do you use?

Comment: I am using Windows 7 Professional 64 bit. I updated the Bios yesterday, and so far, the beeping noise has stopped.

Comment: The beeping noise only occurs for a brief time after startup. Is it the motherboard telling me something is wrong? Or is it just loading?

Comment: It sounds like the Power On Self Test.  When you first turn it on, it tests critical parts of the system before loading the operating system.  It produces a pattern of beeps (one is normal, multiple indicate a problem).  It typically uses a little beeper on the systemboard rather than the speakers.  The meaning of the beeps depends on the BIOS.  Count the beeps the next time you hear it.

Comment: @fixer1234 I found the beeping only happens when I am running Windows. I have since switched completely to Linux and the beeping has stopped.

Comment: It wouldn't be the POST, then.  That happens before any OS is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

I too was getting this annoying beep.

https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkPad-W-Series-Laptops/W520-Fainth-low-tone-beeps/td-p/554213/page/2

here is a link from the lenovo forums where other users get the issue and some fixes. I was able to fix it by disabling the optical drive. you can test this by just opening the cd drive, and the sound will stop for a few seconds.